# Instagram image upload with script

Tags: instagram

So Instagram has blocked every possible way for an individual to use their api to upload an image. Only solution here would be to use a service such as Hootsuite, Later, etc. But these service do not offer a free accessable API as far as my knowledge goes. However, Instagram also added the feature to upload an image from the mobile website interface.
[This question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/41728/is-it-possible-to-upload-images-to-instagram-without-using-proprietary-software) has looked into this, but I'm asking now specificly if there is a new solution for this. I think it should be easily possible to emulate this scenario, seen for example in InstaPy. But does a solution to upload an image to instagram from my server already exist?